# Kanji of そそっかしい

Tags: kanji, etymology, readings

I am wondering about the way to write そそっかしい in kanji, and if this is possible.
 I've found that the な-adjective 粗忽｛そこつ｝, a word with very similar if not identical meaning, can in less common cases be read 粗忽｛そそ｝ as well -- yet my google searches do not seem to like 粗忽っかしい｛そそっかしい｝ at all!

Still, since the meanings of these words are so much alike, I can't help but be suspicious. Of course, I'm aware that そそっかしい is normally written in hiragana. But I am still curious about a connection with kanji, so if anyone on here can enlighten me, I will be very happy.

Comment: For etymology: http://gogen-allguide.com/so/sosokkashii.html Also this could be an interesting read: http://ppnetwork.seesaa.net/article/445558292.html

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-314305 suggests that one author wrote it as 麁相かしい (麁 is a variant of 粗), but I'm unable to trace it further to determine whether this is a standard reading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This kotobank.jp](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-314305) link says that『日本国語大辞典』refers to a *kanji* version of「そそっかしい」as「麁相かしい」, and gives a quote from the novel (section) 式亭三馬『浮世風呂・２・下』:

> 私が一体麁相かしい性で

Here's a page from『浮世風呂』(taken from [人文学オーペンデータ共同利用センター](http://codh.rois.ac.jp/iiif/iiif-curation-viewer/index.html?pages=200015779&pos=141)) with that quote highlighted:

[image]

This is my transcription:

> [image]

If you believe that this *furigana* says「[麁相]{そそっ}か」(refer to a [*hentaigana* chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentaigana)), and trust the authority of『日本国語大辞典』, then「そそっかしい」can be written as「麁相かしい」.

> In the『日本国語大辞典』entry, the only quote including「そそっかしい」which has *kanji* is「麁相かしい」.
>
> Additionally, according to this dictionary,「そそっかしい」is actually just a variant and is derived from「そそかしい」with the addition of the [*sokuon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokuon)「っ」. Under「そそかしい」, more *kanji* variants have been recorded, including
>
> - 『和英語林集成』(1867年初版): 「[粗粗]{そそ}かしい」
> - 夏目漱石『明暗』: 「...彼を[忽卒]{そそか}しく」
>
> *Thanks to @By137 for providing this info*

---

尾崎紅葉『金色夜叉』is another novel which possibly uses that reading:

[image]

My transcription:

> ## [不相變麁相]{あひかはらずそ〻ツ}かしいね

---

In both cases, it looks like「ツ」(or its very close *hentaigana* equivalent「」, [U+1B06A](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1B06A)) is used for what is now「っ」, which may have been common orthographic practice at that time (these two were written around 1800-1900).

Of course, there might be other *kanji* representations of「そそっかしい」used around this era; many of these texts are not digitised (or properly checked after digitisation) so they remain unsearchable on the web.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't have a copy of『日本国語大辞典』to confirm what the dictionary actually says. Also,「麁相かしい」appears twice more on [these two pages](http://codh.rois.ac.jp/iiif/iiif-curation-viewer/index.html?pages=200015779&pos=144).

Comment: Good finding+1. But can't you find another source other than 浮世風呂？ Only 1 source is a bit weak with sorry.

Comment: @KentaroTomono okay, I added another novel which looks like it uses that reading. I don't think I can find any more.

Comment: Feel free to put this info in your answer. I'll delete mine if you do.

Comment: @By137 Thanks, could you re-check whether I paraphrased you correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is seriously fascinating stuff! I'd never even heard of hentaigana before, so you've provided me with something new to dive in as well. :-) I do agree it's suitable to accept this answer over the first one.

Comment: @droooze Looks good to me except that the 送り仮名 in the 夏目漱石 quote was しく only 忽卒{そそか}しく. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering about the way to write そそっかしい in kanji, and if this is possible.
> I've found that the な-adjective 粗忽そこつ, a word with very similar if not identical meaning, can in less common cases be read 粗忽そそ as well -- yet my google searches do not seem to like 粗忽そそっかしい at all!

Your question was nice because I have never paid due attention to this word in Kanji. [So I checked.](http://yuraika.com/sosokkashii/)

The above Yuraika.com, which tells us the etymological origin of a word, says,

> 「そそっかしい」の漢字表記{かんじひょうき｝は不明｛ふめい｝
>
> It is unclear how we express そそっかしい in Kanji.

Although as you found out 粗忽 as a Kanji version 「そそっかしい」、it is yet pronounced as 「そこつ」 but not 「そそっかしい」( [Dictionaries](http://www.manabu-oshieru.com/kanji/nandoku/2/so/so001.html) say only **semantically same** not as a pronunciation. )

### Conclusion

There is no Kanji for そそっかしい。

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I hope you don't delete your answer (maybe just modify it a bit...`There is no Kanji for そそっかしい。` > `A *kanji* representation for そそっかしい is exceedingly rare`). I think the reference which says `「そそっかしい」の漢字表記は不明` shows that the vast majority of people haven't seen the *kanji* for it. The *kanji* representation isn't even recorded as a valid way of writing the word「そそっかしい」in most dictionaries.

Comment: @droooze ah, it's alright. And congrats. But as you say, I bet almost 99.99999% people **today** have never used the Kanji, even nor have ever seen. Even あいかわらず by Ozaki is not literally Japanese Kanji but rather Chinese Kanji. haha.